# Remove space between GridView Groups

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a list of people grouped by the first letter of the name.

The result is as follow :

[image]

The problem is the space between groups D and G, how can I remove it?

The GroupStyle is declare like this :

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Width="150" Height="150" Background="#FFF14B01">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="1,0,0,20">
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextStyle}" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Margin="0,0,80,0" ItemHeight="150" ItemWidth="150" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </GridView.GroupStyle>
```

There is no keys with empty collection in the Key / Value collection.

In fact, if the group 'A' is on 5 columns, each groups will have 5 columns space even if there is only one item.

So, in the picture, D has 3 column space and G too.

Thanks in advance

---

Edit :

Problem solved by adding this:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You should have changed `<VariableSizedWrapGrid Margin="0,0,80,0">` to `<VariableSizedWrapGrid Margin="0"`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of that empty area is that you have empty instances of the class that provides the names and letters. However if there is no such a thing, I guess this would be a solution as well:

Create a property in the source so it returns whether there is an element in the sequence - can be done to return Visibility.

```cs
public Visibility IsVisible
{
        get
        {
        return Key == "" ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }
}
```

Then bind it to the Visibility of the Grid.